# Re-Rendering Datatables ColumnDefs to make Editable using Button On Click

Tags: jquery, datatables

Was wondering if anyone knew a better way of doing this?

I have my normal DataTable initializing on page load.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var oTable;
 oTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
 processing: true,
 serverSide: true,
 ajax: "http://example.com/ajax.php",
 "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                   return '$' + row[2];
                 },
                "targets": 2
            }
              ]
});
});
```

On my page I have a button with an onclick event.

```
<button onclick="editTable">Edit Table</button>
```

This function destroys the current DataTable object, and reinitializes it completely.

```
function editTable() {
     var tables = $.fn.dataTable.tables(true);
     $(tables).DataTable().rows().invalidate('data')
     $(tables).DataTable().clear().destroy();

     var oTable;
     oTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
     processing: true,
     serverSide: true,
     ajax: "http://example.com/ajax.php",
     "columnDefs": [
                {
     "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return '<a id="reviseprice" onclick="change_price(\'' + row[2] + '\');return false;">$'+row[2]+'</a>';
                     },
           "targets": 2
                }
                  ]
    });
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this than destroying the current DataTables instance and reinitalizing it completely so that I can change the columndefs render to, in the example shown above, make the price editable?

Comment: Have you tried to use [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) function?

Comment: Have not tried draw(), no. Will look into thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run few Datatables API that will reloading and re-triggering your data and render call:

**[ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())** - `paging reset`

**table.ajax.reload( null, false )** - `paging retained`

**[draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())** - `paging reset`

**draw(false)** - `paging retained`

> The trick is to have one global variable to store editable status.

**Sample code:**

```
 var editable=false;
 $('#edit').click(function(){
      editable = true;
      table.ajax.reload( null, false );
    });
```

> Inside render function you can filter based on current editable
>   status.

**render code:**

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                  if(editable){
                    return 'editable(\'' + row[2] + '\')';
                  }
                   return row[2];
                 },
                "targets": 2
            }
        ]
```

**Example Demo:**

```js
$.mockjax({
    url: "http://example.com/ajax.php",
    response: function(settings) {
      this.responseText = {
        "draw": settings.data.draw,
        "recordsTotal": 13,
        "recordsFiltered": 13,
        "data": [
          [
            "Airi",
            "Satou",
            "Accountant",
            "Tokyo",
            "28th Nov 08"
          ],
          [
            "Angelica",
            "Ramos",
            "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
            "London",
            "9th Oct 09"
          ],
          [
            "Ashton",
            "Cox",
            "Junior Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "12th Jan 09"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ],
          [
            "Cedric",
            "Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "29th Mar 12"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
});


var editable=false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging":   true,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://example.com/ajax.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                  if(editable){
                    return 'editable(\'' + row[2] + '\')';
                  }
                   return row[2];
                 },
                "targets": 2
            }
        ]
    });
  
    $('#view').click(function(){
      editable = false;
      //table.rows().invalidate().draw(false);
      table.ajax.reload( null, false );
    });
  
    $('#edit').click(function(){
      editable = true;
      //table.rows().invalidate().draw(false);
      //table.ajax.reload();
      table.draw(false);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="edit">EDITABLE</button>
<button id="view">VIEW ONLY</button>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

Comment: Perfect. Works great this way. I was overcomplicating it I think thank you for breaking it down it's actually quite easy.